# SVG <img> in HTML, <title> tooltip not displayed on mouseover

Tags: html, svg

I have a SVG image, that contains <title> elements which are used as tooltips.
When I load the SVG in Mozilla, the tooltips display correctly.

However, when I use the SVG in an HTML document, via the <img> element the tooltips are not displayed on mouseover.

Is it possible to get the tooltips to display correctly?

The HTML is

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
  <head>
    <title>SVG in HTML title test</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <img src="test.svg" />
  </body>
</html>
```

and the SVG is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1" standalone="yes"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.0//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/DTD/svg10.dtd">

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xml:space="preserve" viewBox="0 0 100 100">
  <title>SVG in HTML test</title>
  <g>
    <polygon stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="#0000ff" points="20,20 40,20 40,40 20,40" />
    <title>rectangle</title>
  </g>

  <g>
    <circle stroke="black" stroke-width="1" fill="#ff0000" cx="70" cy="70" r="10" />
    <title>circle</title>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Images (<img> elements etc) are not interactive so title elements within them are non-functional.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using the `object` tag but this might not work for all browsers, I think it only works for the ones which support `HTML5`:

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="test.svg">Browser doesn't support SVG</object>
```

Alternatively, I'm not a big fan of this but what you can try is also using an `iframe`:

```
<iframe src="test.svg"></iframe>
```

This should also work for older browsers... both approaches should show the `tooltips` defined by your `title` tags. I did a quick (successful) test with yours.

Comment: Thanks,
I'll try putting an iframe inside the object, so that newer browsers will use the object element, and older ones the iframe.

Comment: Glad if I could help. Does it now work the way you need it? If this solved your problem I would kindly ask you to accept my answer. Otherwise, please let us know if there is still an issue with the tooltips. Also, as a fallback to the `iframe`, you can still make use of the `image` (without tooltips) - for the worst case. At least using these `tags` does not require using any `javascript` libraries.

Comment: Thanks, it's working for the complex SVG that prompted the question. A fall-back past the <iframe> is probably a bit of overkill, but I'll do it anyway.

Comment: I agree, just wanted to mention it. It will be very unlikely that you have a `real` visitor who has a browser which does not support iframes. However, some browsers might block mixed content. But depends on your audience too I'd say. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Add the appropriate ID’s to the `<title>`:

`<title id="uniqueTitleID">SVG in HTML title test</title>`

On the `<svg>` tag, add:

`aria-labelledby="uniqueTitleID"` (use the title ID)

title should be included in aria-labelledby because it has better screen-reader support than aria-describedby

Comment: This solution is even recommended by Mozillas Developer Network: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img